# getting error when trying to use jquery fileUpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I'm letting the user select files and then trying to programmatically uploading them after they click the upload button using the [jquery fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#programmatic-file-upload) script

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input name="my_image[]" id="my_file" type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

The jquery call looks like this:

```
$('#start-upload').click(function(e) {

    var filesList = $('#my_file')[0].files;
    //var filesList = $('#my_file').prop("files");

    var url = 'photos/index.php';
    $('#my_file').fileupload('send', {
        files: filesList,
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        start: function(e, data) {
            console.log("Upload started");
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log("Upload complete");
        }  
    });
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'send'
```

Any idea what I'm doing?

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory to me.  [The very first section on the page you link to](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#initialization) shows how to initialize the plugin.

Comment: I must be missing the obvious...

Comment: I guess you have to initialize the fileupload with only a JS object as argument before you can call other methods on it (like `send` in this case). The link gilly3 posted shows an example of how to initialize it correctly

Comment: I don't think what you are missing is that obvious, @Paul. I am trying to do a programmatic upload, and getting the same error. The doc does not advise that we have to initialize the plugin before calling `send`, where I assume that passing all required options in the `send` call would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't initialized. Ensure you first have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#my_file').fileupload({ url: 'your_url' ...} );
});
```

Cheers

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it starts an upload as soon files are selected.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Edgar's answer, this is how I set things up to programmatically submit:

```
//Initialize
$('#file').fileupload({
  url: 'someUrl'
});

//Trigger the submit

$('#file').fileupload({
  fileInput: $('#file')
});
```